# Does Java have generic test for equality that also handles nulls?

Tags: java

Is there anywhere in the Java standard libraries that has a static equality function something like this?

```
public static <T> boolean equals(T a, T b)
{
    if (a == null)
        return b == null;
    else if (b == null)
        return false;
    else
        return a.equals(b);
}
```

I just implemented this in a new project `Util` class, for the umpteenth time. Seems unbelievable that it wouldn't ship as a standard library function...

Comment: In native Java, there isn't (AFAIK). This is covered in libraries like [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza from 7 on there is

Comment: @VicSchappert Were we able to answer the question to your satisfaction? Or are you missing some things? If not, you should accept one of the answers below

Comment: @martido Absolutely -- sorry for absentmindedness :)

Comment: @VicSchappert No worries ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In JDK 7 there's [Objects#equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29). From the Javadoc:

> Returns true if the arguments are equal to each other and false
>   otherwise. Consequently, if both arguments are null, true is returned
>   and if exactly one argument is null, false is returned. Otherwise,
>   equality is determined by using the equals method of the first
>   argument.

In addition to the already mentioned function in Apache Commons Lang there's also one in Google Guava, [Objects#equal()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#equal-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-):

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing "If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you."

Comment: I was referring to you undoing my edits. Perhaps there's a bug in stackoverflow where you did not explicitly undo it.

Comment: No, I didn't undo your edit ... would never do that. It took me a while to get that link to Google Guava right. So maybe that's why your edit is gone?

Comment: @SteveKuo Perhaps you submtted an edit while martido was also editing, effectively overriding your edit without martido ever seeing it

Answer (score 5):

Java 7 onward we have JDK 7 [Objects#equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29).

*You can look at the 3rd party libraries too :*

Apache Commons [ObjectUtils#equals()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) , Google's Guava [Objects#equal()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#equal-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) and Spring's [ObjectUtils#nullSafeEquals()](http://static.springsource.org/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/util/ObjectUtils.html#nullSafeEquals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)).